# Finding the number of days between two dates?

Tags: google-sheets

How can I calculate the number of days between two dates in Google Sheets? I tried this: `=DAYS(11/11/2018, 11/08/2018)` and it gives 0, which is definitely not right. I also couldn't seem to get it to work with `=DATEDIF()` or `=MINUS()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all those functions, you need to **put dates in quotes**; otherwise they are treated like (very small) fractions, giving the odd results you found.

So for your original function, structure it like this instead: `=DAYS("11/11/2018", "11/08/2018")` (which, correctly, returns the number 3).